# Xamarin forms contentpresenter goes in wrong row and empty on phone

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms, contentpresenter

I'm having a go at Xamarin Forms trying to create my custom 'GroupBox' control which is a just a grid with two rows. The first row should just show a box with a header . The header has a background rectangle with a label. The second row shows the content via `ContentPresenter` the content goes below in the second row.

I believe I've done the XAML correctly, this is how I'd do it in `WPF`, it shows in the `GroupBox.xaml` Forms Previewer fine, but when I add it into the main page, the content of the Groupbox goes into the first row (the header) instead of the second for some reason within the Previewer.

[image: the content is going into the header]

furthermore, when I attempt to run on an android phone, it just looks like this:

[image: the group boxes are blank frames with no background colour or text]

the group boxes are blank frames with no background colour or text

This is the code of the GroupBox 'user  control'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XForms.GroupBox">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="1" OutlineColor="AliceBlue"/>

    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Red" Margin="1"/>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" TextColor="White" Text="Label!" Margin="2" />

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">   
        <ContentPresenter/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

This code is in the main form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XForms;assembly=XForms"
                 x:Class="XForms.MainPage">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <local:GroupBox Grid.Row="0">
                    <Label Text="I'm some content 1"/>
                </local:GroupBox>

                <local:GroupBox Grid.Row="1">
                    <Label Text="I'm some content 2"/>
                </local:GroupBox>

                <local:GroupBox Grid.Row="2">
                    <Label Text="I'm some content 3"/>
                </local:GroupBox>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage>
```

in the main page XAML I can add a grid row to the label, even though there is no grid in the content, and it will work in the previewer -- but it's still blank on the phone (Which is most important).

```
  <local:GroupBox Grid.Row="0">
                    <Label Text="I'm some content 1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                </local:GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what is the `Frame` for, but it is currently covering the `BoxView` and labels and thus made them invisible. Comment out the `Frame` and you will see the labels and `BoxView` again.

> I believe I've done the XAML correctly, this is how I'd do it in WPF, it shows in the GroupBox.xaml Forms Previewer fine, but when I add it into the main page, the content of the Groupbox goes into the first row (the header) instead of the second for some reason within the Previewer.

`ContentPresenter` doesn't work like that.In Xamarin.Forms, it is generally used in `ControlTemplate`. For usage of ContentPresenter, please refer to [this blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/app-theming-with-xamarin-forms-control-templates/).

In your case, if you want to ContentPresenter to work. Instead of using `Grid` for `GroupBox`, you can use `ContentView` for `GroupBox` like below:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class GroupBox : ContentView
{
    public GroupBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

GroupBox.xaml:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Demo.GroupBox">
<ContentView.ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.2*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--<Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="1" OutlineColor="AliceBlue"></Frame>-->
            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Red" Margin="1"  />
            <Label Grid.Row="0" TextColor="White" Text="Label!" Margin="2" />
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <ContentPresenter/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ContentView.ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Great, it works on the phone and they are in the right position now. many thanks. I was using the Frame to create an outline around the box, I probably should have mentioned it before.